# WordPress inquiry form without saving into DB

Tags: wordpress, forms, contact-form, mail-form

I need WordPress plugin for inquiry form, which send data to mail only. Don't want to save into DB because large database needed to store into database

Answer (score -1):

```
You can use the https://wordpress.org/plugins/contact-form-7/ and with help of this plugin, you can create custom fields as per you need an inquiry form.

In future, if you need to store data in DB then there is an additional plugin 

https://wordpress.org/plugins/cf7-database/
https://wordpress.org/plugins/save-contact-form-7/
https://wordpress.org/plugins/contact-form-submissions/
```